# posting empty data error to website

Tags: c#, class, post, web

i want to post data to website with Form app. I'm calling a class

```
     string name = pst.Text;
    WebClientEx Wex = new WebClientEx(name);
```

and in the class:

```
public class WebClientEx : WebClient
    {
        public CookieContainer _cookies = new CookieContainer(); 

       public string Newpost;
       public  WebClientEx(string name)
       {
           name = Newpost;

       }
```

Im posting data with this method:

```
public string getPost()
       {         
            WebClientEx client = new WebClientEx();
            CQ dom = CQ.Create(Page);
                  data.Add("value", Newpost);
```

however Newpost is always empty. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do

```
public  WebClientEx(string name)
   {
       Newpost = name;
   }
```